# JavaFX TilePane what tile user clicked

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TilePane` where each cell (tile) contains an image of a movie so f.e.:[image]

In Java it looks like this:

```
    public void searchMovieBtn_Clicked(){

        searchmoviesTilePane.getChildren().clear();
        MoviesAPI mvAPI = new MoviesAPI();
        List<FilmSearchResult> filmInfoList = mvAPI.findFilm(searchmovieTextField.getText());

        Task task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override public Void call() {
                for(int i=0; i<filmInfoList.size(); i++){
                    updateProgress(i+1, filmInfoList.size());
                    if(filmInfoList.get(i).getImageURL() != null) {
                        Image searchItemImage = new Image(filmInfoList.get(i).getImageURL());
                        ImageView searchItemImageView = new ImageView(searchItemImage);
                        searchItemImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            searchmoviesTilePane.getChildren().add(searchItemImageView);
                        });
                    }
                }

                return null;
            }
        };
        progressIndicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        new Thread(task).start();
}
```

My goal is to let a user ability to click "images" with a particular movie in order to show more details about this film. But I am not able to do that through f.e. `getPickResults` and `intersectedNodes` because it's just an image. I would be thankful for any advice how I could implement this feature

EDITED:

```
for(int j=0; j<searchmoviesTilePane.getChildren().size(); j++){
                searchmoviesTilePane.getChildren().get(j).setOnMouseEntered(e -> searchmoviesItem_MouseEntered(e.getPickResult().toString()));
            }
```

But what's next ? how am I able to find out what exactly "image" user clicked ?

Comment: Just register mouse listeners on each image view...

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but what's next ? Let's asume that I've added what is under `EDITED` paragraph. The problem is that I am not able to recognize which `item` in a `TilePane` was clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just register a mouse listener on the image view:

```
Task task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override public Void call() {
        for(int i=0; i<filmInfoList.size(); i++){
            updateProgress(i+1, filmInfoList.size());
            if(filmInfoList.get(i).getImageURL() != null) {
                FilmSearchResult film = filmInfoList.get(i);
                Image searchItemImage = new Image(film.getImageURL());
                ImageView searchItemImageView = new ImageView(searchItemImage);
                searchItemImageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

                searchItemImageView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> showDetails(film));

                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    searchmoviesTilePane.getChildren().add(searchItemImageView);
                });
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
};


// ....

private void showDetails(FilmSearchResult film) {
    // show details for film...
}
```